# Get one id to multiple data in other table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016

i have two table one is software(only one software id) and 2nd is downloadurl(this table multiple softwareurl in one software id), then how to create a store Procedures in one software id to get all downloadUrl in one store Procedures.

i get all data in software id with multiple softwareurl...

Comment: Please show what you have done till now in terms of code and your logic. Only then we can help you in your query.

Comment: To do what? What are you actually asking here?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.